# Has anyone received a compile error that makes you use , instead of ; in an axios call?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Compile error unless I use a comma in an axios call.

Here is the error. 'Unexpected token, expected ","'

in a vue I have an axios call.

```
axios
            .get('/api/messages/'+this.issue)
            .then(response => (

                this.messages = response.data;

                console.log(response.data);

            ))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I get a compile error if I don't use commas.

```
axios
            .get('/api/messages/'+this.issue)
            .then(response => (

                this.messages = response.data,

                console.log(response.data)

            ))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I also get a compile error if I try to run an if() statement in .then(). I'm using the latest versions of Laravel, Vue and Axios. Has amyone else had this issue? or have a fix?

Comment: That's because you're using `()` instead of `{}` in your then callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Issue

Your error is because javascript expects `response => ()` to be a statement that is returned.

You can think of it like saying `response => return (/* code */)`

### Solution

Instead, in order to use the arrow function without an immediate return, switch to brackets:

```
response => {}
```

That way, javascript no longer expects a statement that returns right away, and will execute like a function with the full power of js.

Hope this helps!